# Hexadecimal NSString to int Objective C

Tags: objective-c, int, nsstring, hex, converters

I am currently struggling to figure out how to convert a Hexadecimal NSString into a calculated int via Objective C.
I am trying to have an Objective C Function that would get inputed with an NSString eg. Like this:

```
NSString *hexString = @"0x0f";
```

and return the decimal value (as an int):

```
int hexValue = 15; (converted)
```

eg. use this website to learn how to get the decimal of Hexadecimal:
http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

If someone could show me how to do this this would be great thanks :D
(in Objective C) and please try to make the code a small as possible :)

Answer (score -1):

Don't Worry I figured it out. If anyone else has this question then you can use my answer:

```
NSString *hexString = @"0x0f"; // hexString is inputted

unsigned value = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
[scanner scanHexInt:&value];

int decimalValue = (int)value; // decimalValue is outputted
```

Hope this helps for anyone who needs this :)

Comment: BTW: caution signs exist for a reason and you should not just ignore them, that is **very bad advice**. `scanHexInt:` expects a pointer to an `unsigned int` and you are passing a pointer to a `long`. Fortunately for you passing a larger chunk of memory than required and the endianness of the CPU avoided disaster.

Comment: Ok thx, I fixed it

Comment: How does one get the SIGNED value  (signed int) back from hexString ?